# Настройка уровня изоляции в клиентском приложении EXCEL

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Разрабатываю приложение на C# которое вытаскивает данные из MS SQL в файл EXCEL и после их редактирования обновляет данные в БД. Главная проблема это изолировать действия пользователей друг от друга, т.е. над одной строкой не могут одновременно работать несколько пользователей (своего рода пессимистическая блокировка строк). Например юзер выделяет несколько строк в таблице и нажимает кнопку взять на редактирование, при этом ему выходит сообщение о том, что строки уже заняты.
Для получения и редактирования строк планировал использовать Entity Framework, однако он позволяет реализовать только оптимистичную модель доступа, что неприемлемо по условиям задачи.
Думал над темой записывать(удалять) ID используемых строк в отдельную таблицу  и при взятии на редактирование проверять их наличие. Однако такой подход очевидно несёт в себе две проблемы:
1.Значительно увеличится время работы программы за счёт insert/delete;
2.Если клиентское приложение вылетит - строки останутся в статусе "заняты".
Может быть есть еще какой-то путь изолировать строки на долгий промежуток времени (юзер должен иметь возможность работать со строками неограниченное кол-во времени)?   Может можно как-то приладить TransactionScope для этих целей?

Comment: В *Excel* плохо организован совместный доступ, много ограничений. Почему бы не работать с *Google*-таблицей?

Comment: 1) Вы правильно думали завести еще таблицу
2) Помимо таблицы заведите маркер "онлайна" пользователя, если маркер устарел(например раз в 10 минут ваш софт обновляет маркер) - данные освобождаются. 
3) вместо отдельной таблицы - можно завести в таблице с данными поле, в которое писать маркер блокировки с принадлежностью к пользователю(например писать в строку id пользователя, а если строка свободна - 0).

Comment: от себя добавлю к ответу @ВладимирКлыков, заведите на сервере джоб который бедт мониторить свежесть маркеров и если надо апдейтить маркеры. Так вы будете застрахованы от падения апликухи

Comment: Большое спасибо за советы.

Comment: Вот вопрос возник. Как отследить активных юзеров на стороне БД. Сделал джоб на основе sp_who, однако он показывает только тех из них которые проявляют постоянную активность, подчищая все неиспользованные соединения минут эдак через 10. А что если один из моих подопечных решит взять строки на редактирование и скажем уйти обедать... Как не удалить блокировки строк в этом случае?

Comment: Вообще не нужно никакого блокирования. Добавьте какое-то поле Status, разрешите пользователям выбирать для редактирования только поля со статусом, например 0. Выбрали данные - взвели статус в 1, вернули - сбросили в 0. Нужны, наверное, еще поля Changer + LastUpdateDate - анализируя их в какой-то джобе, можно будет сбрасывать Status по каким-то подходящим критериям.

Comment: Denis Rubashkin - доброго дня. Именно так и происходит в данный момент, но есть тонкость. Что делать если приложение вылетело  до сохранения данных? Кто сможет в таком случае поправить статус с 1 на 0? Выше предлагался вариант с "маркером онлайн пользователя", но при использовании sp_who мы увидим только тех пользователей которые были активны в последние 10-15 минут, остальные удаляются. А как увидеть пользователей которые взвели статус (1) и отвлеклись на другие дела? Их нельзя выбрасывать.