# Поиск активных юзеров БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Делаю приложение на C# которое забирает(возвращает) данные с MS SQL. Дело в том, что необходимо в момент работы юзера над строкой заблокировать доступ других пользователей к этой строке. Решил эту проблему созданием маркера занятости строки. Однако, может возникнуть ситуация аварийного выхода из программы при котором маркер занятости не удалится.
Ранее поднимал этот вопрос тут - [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890571/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-excel)
Одна из рекомендаций была отслеживать на стороне сервера активных пользователей и при их исчезновении чистить маркер занятости. Пробовал реализовать это через джоб на основе `sp_who`, однако он показывает только тех из них которые проявляют постоянную активность, подчищая все неиспользованные соединения минут эдак через 10. А что если один из моих подопечных решит взять строки на редактирование и скажем уйти обедать... Так как не удалить блокировки строк в этом случае?
Для работы с данными использую `Entity Framework`.

Comment: А еще пользователь может уйти в отпуск. Или уволиться... Это как раз и является причиной того, что пессимистическая блокировка крайне не рекоменуется к использованию.

Comment: Можно отталкиваться не от пользователя, а от строки/маркера: если в течение Х секунд пользователь ничего не делал со строкой, то маркер снимается

Comment: Оптимистичная блокировка в моём случае неприемлема, моя БД связана с большим количеством редактируемых данных. А случай с отпуском самый легко решаемый - коллеги по отделу сами найдут смутьяна и отключат его  комп, в добавок сопроводив отеческими наставлениями и парой оплеух.

Comment: Regent - спасибо за совет, однако это опять приведёт к ситуации когда юзер бездействовал скажем 20 минут, а я его принудительно отключу. Возможно у него были в приложении подготовлены, но еще не сохранены данные, скажем он в течении часа разносил счета и при попытке их сохранить выяснилось, что его уже отключили... Будут проблемы.

Comment: _Так как не удалить блокировки строк в этом случае?_ - может, наоборот, удалить? Перед уходом на обед освободи ресурсы другим людям, дай им поработать. Или это сделает система за тебя.

Comment: Не рассматривали возможность применить [WAITFOR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Ага, пользователь даже час может держать блокировку... Может, тогда следует периодически показывать ему напоминание: не забыл ли он разлочить? В зависимости от его выбора либо продолжаем удерживать блокировку, либо освобождаем ее.

Comment: Мой совет - эмпирически вычислить необходимое и достаточное время на редактирование и безусловно разблокировать записи через это время (некий аналог LOCK_TIMEOUT). Если кто-то ушел на обед, забил, забыл, умер в конце концов - это не должно отражаться на доступности данных для других пользователей. А может быть кто-нить решит просто подгадить и саботировать работу? Описанная работа приложения никак не завязана на SQL-активности, поэтому никакой анализ типа sp_who2 ничего не даст. А вот пара раз повторного редактирования быстро отучит от "ухода на обед" с блокированными записями.